Is it possible that iOS follows content of /etc/hosts file of connected Mac device?
For the purpose of testing on real iOS device with dev tools I am connecting an iPhone with a Mac and then using Safari to open inspector. This is pretty straight forward procedure which works.
In my case I want to test a page that is still in development on a computer in the local network. This brings the question - is it possible that iOS follows the /etc/hosts file of MacOS so that I can open the page I want?
Tried to simply edit the hosts file of the computer, but iOS was still unable to resolve the address.

That's an interesting question but unfortunately I think the answer is just "no" to that one :/
